# How to convert select row_number query to delete query on PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete, row-number

I have a query like this which is working well on postgresql server;

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT s_o_i,
          row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY g_i,
                                          c
                             ORDER BY o_s DESC) AS rank
   FROM b_o) b_o
WHERE rank > 1
  AND m_t < CURRENT_DATE - interval '1 months'
```

When I convert this to this query;

```
DELETE
FROM
  (SELECT s_o_i,
          row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY g_i,
                                          c
                             ORDER BY o_s DESC) AS rank
   FROM b_o) b_o
WHERE rank > 1
  AND m_t < CURRENT_DATE - interval '1 months'
```

It throws an error like this;

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 3:   (SELECT s_o_i,
```

why does it throw an error on delete query?

```
DELETE
FROM
  (SELECT s_o_i,
          row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY g_i,
                                          c
                             ORDER BY o_s DESC) AS rank
   FROM b_o) b_o
WHERE rank > 1
  AND m_t < CURRENT_DATE - interval '1 months'
```

I expect it to run and delete the records on the clauses.

Comment: You can't delete data from a query result. Deletion can be done on a table or on a cte. What exactly do you want to do? Could you please show some sample data and the expected result after the intended deletion?

Comment: I want to delete the rows with the same clauses that I used in select query because I need that `rank` value to delete the records.

Comment: Can you show me an example with CTE? Maybe I could use that `rank` with that

Comment: Ok, I would use a cte and delete from its result, see here a documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 (I know, it's a documentation of SQL Server, but that functionality doesn't differ to Postgres)

Comment: Can you show me how to convert the select query that I wrote as an example? I don't know cte

Comment: You can only delete records in a table or an unmaterialized view that's selecting from only one table. Deleting from a cte makes as much sense as deleting from a subquery that just gave you an error: they both live for the duration of the main query, so filtering something out from them with a `where` is sufficient. See [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/gSYV2rdf). Also, use [adequate RDBMS docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) - the functionality does differ.

Comment: @Zegarek I don't understand what you want to say with your comment, but anyway, the last part of your answer just shows what I was talking about: Use a CTE and delete data found by that CTE. And such things are just shown in the documentations. In my opinion, the functionality of CTE's required here does not depend on the DBMS (while of course, generally functions of course differ between Postgres and other DBMS). I think it would have been better if OP had read the documentation and written the SQL on their own (or at least try it) rather than you just do their work.

Comment: But I agree, providing the DBMS-specific documentation should be prefered, I will do so next time.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Good point. I forgot to state that I was referring to *"Deletion can be done on a table or on a cte."* - the idea was to clarify that a bit. About the docs, I did suspect you meant the docs don't differ *much for this case* - again, added that for clarity. Not much to disagree with on the last point.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your aim is to remove all records from each group of `(g_i, c)` from more than a month ago, except for the latest/highest `o_s`: [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/S9DIWJt8)

```sql
DELETE FROM b_o WHERE ctid in 
(   SELECT ctid
    FROM 
    (   SELECT  ctid,
                row_number() OVER w AS rank                             
        FROM b_o 
        WHERE m_t < CURRENT_DATE - interval '1 months'
        WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY g_i, c ORDER BY o_s DESC)
    ) as alias
    WHERE rank > 1
);
```

1. You were trying to delete records from a subselect instead of your table `b_o`, which isn't syntactically correct and doesn't make much sense because the subquery table lives only for the duration of the outer query.
2. You referred to `m_t` column outside the subquery without selecting it there first, so it wouldn't be recognised.
3. If `s_o_i` column uniquely identifies records in the table, you can use it instead of [`ctid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html).
4. In this case [common table expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) aren't necessary, but you can use one to flatten things a bit:

```sql
WITH cte AS 
(   SELECT  ctid,
            row_number() OVER w AS rank                             
    FROM b_o 
    WHERE m_t < CURRENT_DATE - interval '1 months'
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY g_i, c ORDER BY o_s DESC)
)
DELETE FROM b_o WHERE ctid in 
(   SELECT ctid
    FROM cte
    WHERE rank > 1
);
```